# What is the name of partition without pairwise disjoint property?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Wiki definition of partition:

> Equivalently, a family of sets P is a partition of X if and only if all of the following conditions hold:[2]
>
> 1. P does not contain the empty set.
> 2. The union of the sets in P is equal to X. (The sets in P are said to cover X.)
> 3. The intersection of any two distinct sets in P is empty. (We say the elements of P are pairwise disjoint.)

If we remove the third condition, does the result sets have specific name in set theory?

Comment: A covering family.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Does that include condition 1 (honest question)?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt No, it doesn't.  I was writing a comment to that effect when yours appeared: The point of partitions is the disjointness requirement, so families of sets without this property are not usually singled out. I would specify "a covering family of nonempty sets" in case we care about condition 1.

Comment: So, There is no specific name for the sets which have simultaneously first and second conditions?

Comment: @TailofGodzilla As said, a cover of $X$ by non-empty sets.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Wait I thought covering family of A is a family sets whose union is a [superset of A rather than equals A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology))?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Same question

Comment: @BCLC you can say “a cover of $X$ by non-empty subsets of $X$. “ no special name for that.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Cool. Post as answer?